# QVideoFilterRunnable does not show the changes I made

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qml

I am trying to make a Video filter that detects faces with MediaPipe. I will work with multiple cameras and I preferred this way because I use qml. But I have a problem.

The operations I do in the QVideoFilterRunnable class do not appear in the VideoOutput component as an image. I can't understand why this is happening.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtMultimedia 5.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import CustomFilter 1.0

Item {
    width:1280
    height:720

    Camera {
        id: camera
    }

    FaceDetectionFilter {
        id: myFaceDetectionFilter
    }

    VideoOutput {
        id: viewfinder
        filters: [ myFaceDetectionFilter ]
        source: camera
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

```
mp_face_detection = mp.solutions.face_detection
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils

class FaceDetectionFilterRunnable(QVideoFilterRunnable):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def run(self, _input, surface, flags):
        return self.transform(_input)
    
    def processFrame(self, frame: QVideoFrame) -> QImage:
        img = frame.image().convertToFormat(QImage.Format_RGB888)
        img = self.QImageToCvMat(img)
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)

        with mp_face_detection.FaceDetection( model_selection=0, min_detection_confidence=0.5) as face_detection:
            img=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            results = face_detection.process(img)
            if results.detections:
                for detection in results.detections:
                    mp_drawing.draw_detection(img, detection)

        img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        height, width, _ = img.shape

        bytesPerLine = 3 * width
        qImg = QImage(img.data, width, height, bytesPerLine, QImage.Format_RGB888)
        return qImg

    def filterAcceptsVideoFrame(self, frame: QVideoFrame) -> bool:
        return True

    def transform(self, frame: QVideoFrame) -> QVideoFrame:
        img = self.processFrame(frame)
        
        if not img.isNull():
            return QVideoFrame(img)
        return frame
    def QImageToCvMat(self,incomingImage):
        '''  Converts a QImage into an opencv MAT format  '''
        incomingImage = incomingImage.convertToFormat(QImage.Format_RGB32)
        width = incomingImage.width()
        height = incomingImage.height()
        ptr = incomingImage.constBits()
        arr = np.array(ptr).reshape(height, width, 4)  #  Copies the data
        return arr

class FaceDetectionFilter(QAbstractVideoFilter):
    def createFilterRunnable(self):
        return FaceDetectionFilterRunnable(self)
```

I am introducing the filter to qml with the following code.

```
qmlRegisterType(FaceDetectionFilter, "CustomFilter", 1, 0, "FaceDetectionFilter")
```

Comment: Looks like your VideoOutput is missing an `anchors.fill: parent`

Comment: The operations in the QVideoFilterRunnable class might not be appearing in the VideoOutput component as an image because there could be an issue with the implementation of the filter or the QML code. Double-check the implementation of the filter and ensure that it is properly registered in QML. Additionally, ensure that the camera and filter are properly connected to the VideoOutput component.

Comment: @StephenQuan When I added this anchors.fill:parent, the result did not change.

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk  When I remove the filter in VideoOutput, Camera and VideoOutput work fine. However, when I add the filter, the blank screen remains. I couldn't find where I made a mistake.